# Create Two dimensional Array of Arrays with two variable types in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array

You can create a two dimensional array of one type of variable in swift with:

```
var array2D: [[String]] = [["hi", "bye"], ["hello", "goodbye"]]
```

I want to create a two dimensional array with the second variable a Float along the following lines:

```
var array2d2types = [[String,Float]] = [["height",1],["width",2]]
```

But this gives error: `Cannot assign to immutable expression of type '[[Any]]'`

How can I create an array of arrays each of which has a String and a Float?

Comment: Use a tuple (or a custom struct) instead.

Comment: Leo, I tried to downcast from Any to Float and ran into problems.

Comment: Don't do that I would suggest you using an array of CGSize objects `let sizes: [CGSize] = [.init(width: 2, height: 1)]`

Comment: `Using width and height may have been misleading These could be any string` and why not to think of them generically what you will do with key names in your app flow ????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swift arrays are homogeneous, so you cannot store different typed elements in the same array. However, you can achieve your goals using an array of tuples instead of nested arrays.

```
let array: [(String,Float)] = [("height",1),("width",2)]
```

You can access the tuples using the normal subscript syntax

```
let firstTuple = array[0]
```

and the elements of the tuple using dot syntax

```
let height = firstTuple.0
let heightValue = firstTuple.1
```

However, you should use a custom struct or even better the built-in `CGSize` for storing height-width values.

Comment: How would I access these?  Would I access one tuple using array[0]? And could I access height/width as let mystring =  array[0][0] and 1/2 as let myfloat = array[0][1]

Comment: `let mystring = array[0].0` and `let myfloat = array[0].1`

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should use a custom `struct` if you want to store various types.  This has the added benefit of allowing you to access those values with a meaningful name instead of just an index.  Use an array of tuples and `.map(Record.init)` to initializes the array of structures.

```
struct Record {
    var string: String
    var float: Float
}

var records = [("height",  1), ("width", 2)].map(Record.init)

print(records[0].string)  // "height"
print(records[0].float)   // 1.0
```

Comment: **This is My API data** ``"publisherPlans": [ [
"Name","Free","Prime"],["Book Sell",9999,9999],["Book Bulk Sell",0,9999]]`` And I want To fetch all data and set to the View, I am trying this Model ``struct PublisherPlansModel: Codable {
    let publisherPlans: [[String]]
}``